# Gef edit part for emf model

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am creating a GEF editor from an EMF model; say the model name is StartEvent, and it has properties like ID, and name.

In the edit part, I have two labels: one for displaying the small circle, and another one for displaying the name. I have implemented the handleBounds interface in the figure class, and I return the bounds of the icon label so that when I click the figure the icon only gets selected else if you don implement handleBounds interface the whole figure will be selected.

Both the icon label and name label must be selectable, and I must be able to move the name label away from it.

The name property of the StartEvent model is mapped to the name label.

I do understand that every thing in gef is an edit part. Your answer may be that the name label should also be an separate edit part, but the name is not an Model; it is a model's property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the label to behave like any other GEF element (movable, selectable, etc) you have to create an `EditPart` for the label. It doesn't matter that the label is not a model entity, you will have to create an `EditPart` for this label using some special workaround, like having a special class that contains the label in the figure (and not a simple String) which can be identified by the `EditPartFactory` of your editor. From what I know, there is no other way to do this.